# rsync in daemon mode: preserve absolute directory structure

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to backup some folders with rsync launched on daemon mode. Basically the client launch this command:

```
   rsync --delete -avz -R -e "ssh -i ${KEY}" ${SERVER}::${MODULE} {DST_DIR}
```

the server has the public key on its authorized_keys file:

```
    command="rsync --server --daemon --config /root/rsync.conf"
```

and here is the rsync.conf file containing folders I want to backup:

```
    uid=0
    gid=0
    read only = true
    use chroot = true
    [backup]
    path = /root
    path = /etc
```

The problem here is that the content of these folders is copied and not its absolute path. I would like /etc/etc_content and /root/root_content in my ${DST_DIR} and what I get is the content of /etc (I presume /root is synchronized first, and then /etc, which delete /root content... Ouch).

I am pretty sure there is a way to force rsync to preserve absolute path. I have tried with the -R option without success. I have also tried without use chroot.

How can I get it through?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right with **"-R"** option to use relative paths but it works a bit different way. The **${MODULE}** exports exactly the  portion of rsync server's filesystem which is defined by **"path"** parameter.

You should have only one **"path"** parameter per **"module"** section defined. This explains why you can see /root content first and /etc later as it seems to be overwritten when multiple path parameters are specified.

I would either try to define a module per a directory I want to backup

```
uid=0
gid=0
read only = true
use chroot = true

[root]
path = /root

[etc]
path = /etc
```

and then call rsync over all these modules

```
for MODULE in root etc; do
  rsync -avzR $SERVER::$MODULE $DST_DIR/$MODULE
done
```

Or I would export wider portion of the server's filesystem with single module section

```
uid=0
gid=0
read only = true
use chroot = true

[root]
path = /
```

And  backup requied directories

```
rsync -avzR $SERVER::$MODULE/root  $SERVER::$MODULE/etc $DST_DIR
```

Both ways will preserve the original/absolute  directory structure you requested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; The fact is I want to restrict the list on client side (If a cracker get access to backup server, he could decide to switch backup files to /etc/shadow for instance) and I would like if possible a unique [backup] module. I think we can manage this with filter or include/exclude rsync.conf options.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way with the include options; my rsync.conf file now looks like this:

```
    uid=0
    gid=0
    read only = true
    use chroot = true
    [backup]
    path = /
    include /etc/*** /root/*** /usr/local/etc/***
    exclude /***
```

I can then retrieve the folders with their absolute path, but another trouble appears:

The problem here is that the synchronization is only working for included directories directly below / aka /etc/* and /root/* and it is not working for /usr/local/etc/*

The same problem occurs when I tries with the include from keyword and fill these folders into the specified included_from file.

I am kind of desperate; Either this is not possible to perform what I want with rsync, or I am missing something obvious? man explanation for rsync is quite tough. dsumsky, thanks for you answer, and I am trying to think I should adopt your solution after all.